# In Android, Is it possible to make Text Tag separation in editext Like Stack overflow (see the image)?

Tags: android, android-edittext, tags

I want to create this kind of separation between commas(,)?  like StackOverflow Tags [image: editext field]

Comment: https://github.com/qiugang/EditTag

Comment: Seems you need to create a custom view for that. There is not built in sdk functionalty

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin yes, this I want to implement, can you put it as an answer, I will accept it?

Comment: OK, I will post it as answer

Comment: You need to create spannable or use material chip view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import me.originqiu.library.EditTag;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SwitchCompat.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private EditTag editTagView;

    private SwitchCompat statusSwitchView;

    private List<String> tagStrings = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTagView = (EditTag) findViewById(R.id.edit_tag_view);
        statusSwitchView = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.status_switch);
        statusSwitchView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tagStrings.add("test" + i);
        }
        //Set tag add callback before set tag list
        editTagView.setTagAddCallBack(new EditTag.TagAddCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTagAdd(String tagValue) {
                if ("test1".equals(tagValue)) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
        editTagView.setTagDeletedCallback(new EditTag.TagDeletedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTagDelete(String deletedTagValue) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, deletedTagValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        editTagView.setTagList(tagStrings);

        editTagView.addTag("hello world!");
        editTagView.removeTag("test3");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        editTagView.setEditable(isChecked);
    }
}
```

In activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="me.originqiu.edittag.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <me.originqiu.library.EditTag
            android:id="@+id/edit_tag_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:input_layout="@layout/view_sample_input_tag"
            app:tag_layout="@layout/view_sample_tag" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/status_switch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="open editable status" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In view_sample_input_tag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<me.originqiu.library.MEditText
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:minWidth="56dp"
    android:drawablePadding="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxEms="30"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:hint="Add Tag "
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_clr"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

In view_sample_tag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_sample_tag"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

See here for more details: https://github.com/qiugang/EditTag/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/view_sample_tag.xml