# put # before the word written edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

how to put # character before the word in edittext?

what I want : I wanna put # character before the every word written in edit text

every word starts with #

for example :

#hello #world #hi

---

Comment: See `TextWatcher` with `addTextChangedListener`.

Comment: sample code please!. I need help

Comment: See my answer for this question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094990/in-android-is-it-possible-to-make-this-kind-of-separation-in-editext/61095269#61095269

Comment: That's not a simple example. You can also search for libraries that use EditText masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `TextWatcher`.

```
class SharpWordsTextWatcher: TextWatcher {

    private var addSharp: Boolean = false
    private var isEmpty = false

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
        if(addSharp) {
            s.insert(s.length - 1, "#")
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        isEmpty = s.isEmpty() || s.last() == ' '
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        addSharp = isEmpty && s.last() != ' ' && count != 0
    }

}
```

And add this to your `EditText`.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(SharpWordsTextWatcher())
```

Comment: @tsniso I have no much time to test it well, so maybe you need to do improvements and some fixes. But this is good point for you to go ahead with this solution. Thank You.

Comment: thank u :) one more question =) 
can I put it a limit ? for example just let 4 # let

Comment: So only first 4 words with #?

Comment: you need to have counter for that, so when to riches it don't append more #-s. And there you need also to decrement that counter when deleting the text. If I have more time I will edit the answer to include this as well

Comment: could you help me when u awaiable ?